# How to create crunch library using Maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to generate crunch folder using maven (the library is auto generated using eclipse in \bin\res\crunch).

I need this generated folder in order to use 9patch images a.k.a XXX.9.png
Has anyone managed to generate it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution... In order to use maven we need to add the following ant plugin to run crunch:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target name="-crunch">
                        <exec executable="aapt" taskName="crunch">
                            <arg value="crunch" />
                            <arg value="-S" />
                            <arg path="${project.basedir}\res" />
                            <arg value="-C" />
                            <arg path="${project.build.directory}\crunch" />
                        </exec>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```